# Is there any closed form solution for this integral?

Tags: integration

I was wondering if any closed form solution exists for the following integral? The integral seams to be convergent and it can be solved numerically. However, I want to know if it can be expressed based on known functions (gamma, Bessel, etc.)?

$\int_{x=0}^\infty {(ax+b)}^{c}{\left(\frac{d}{x}+h\right)}^{f}{x}^{-1}\mathrm{d}x$

$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $h$, and $f$ are real numbers.

I have tried integration by part but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can draw some constants away: $a^ch^f\int_{x=0}^\infty {(x+\frac ba)}^{c}{\left(x+\frac hd\right)}^{f}{x}^{-1-f}\mathrm{d}x$. The resulting integral is more complex that the incomplete Beta.

Comment: The integral diverges whenever all parameters $a,b,c,d,h,f$ is positive....

Comment: @achille hui Due to the nature of the problem, it is unlikely that all parameters become positive at the same time

Comment: @Monas That still leave some *a lot* of ugly casework, unless you can provide more specific conditions for the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an expression (given by a CAS, for sure)
$$I=\frac{\pi  b^c d^f \csc (\pi  (c-f))}{\Gamma (-c) \Gamma (-f)} A$$ with
$$A=\Gamma (-c)^2 \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^c \left(\frac{h}{d}\right)^{f-c} \,
   _2\tilde{F}_1\left(-c,-c;-c+f+1;\frac{b h}{a d}\right)-$$ $$\Gamma (-f)^2
   \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^f \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(-f,-f;c-f+1;\frac{b h}{a
   d}\right)$$ where appears the regularized hypergeometric function.

The conditions are
$$\left(\Re\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\geq 0\lor \frac{b}{a}\notin
   \mathbb{R}\right)\land \Re(c)<0\land \Re(f)<0\land
   \left(\Re\left(\frac{d}{h}\right)\geq 0\lor \frac{d}{h}\notin
   \mathbb{R}\right)\land \Re(b)>0\land \Re(d)>0$$

Now, have fun with it §

Comment: Thanks a lot, Claude!

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici Could you please elaborate more on how you derived the above equation? Much appreciated!

Comment: @Monas. Guess what ? I used a CAS to produce the monster.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part you referred to a CAS in your original post. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm going to solve a similar integral using a CAS. Could you please tell me which CAS did you use to solve the above integral? Thanks!

Comment: @Monas. For this one, I used Wolfram Cloud (that is to say Mathematica).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Claude for the prompt reply. Really appreciate that. Cheers!